# How to manage visibility of elements in a stepped form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with steps.
I want other elements to appear after user passes one step.
There should be only one step visible at a time.

I tried for to use a  boolean state variable without any luck. All steps appear after passing one.

```
return (
  <UserConsumer>
    {value => {
      //const {dispatch} = value;
      return (
        <div>
          <Animation pose={visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}>
            <div className="card col-md-12 mb-4">
              <div className="card-body">
                <form onSubmit={this.changeVisibility}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <Text text="Adınız ve Soyadınız" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <Input ph="Ad ve Soyad" />
                  </div>
                  <Button clickText="İleri" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Animation>

          <Animation pose={!visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}>
            {queue.push(
              <div className="card col-md-12 mb-4">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <form onSubmit={this.changeVisibility}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <Text text="E-mail adresiniz" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <Input ph="E-mail" />
                    </div>
                    <Button clickText="İleri" />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>,
            )}
          </Animation>
        </div>
      )
    }}
  </UserConsumer>
)
```

Comment: what is your current output at view ?

Comment: Only show first div. If clicked button, hidden first but not show second

Comment: why are you doing  `queue.push(` in second Animation component, why not render as the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this based on your comment that it hides the first one but doesn't display the second one is because you are calling the push which will return the length of new array. So instead of elements from second Animation component it will display a number, fix:

```
return (
  <UserConsumer>
    {value => {
      //const {dispatch} = value;
      return (
        <div>
          <Animation pose={visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}>
            <div className="card col-md-12 mb-4">
              <div className="card-body">
                <form onSubmit={this.changeVisibility}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <Text text="Adınız ve Soyadınız" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <Input ph="Ad ve Soyad" />
                  </div>
                  <Button clickText="İleri" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Animation>

          <Animation pose={!visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}>
              <div className="card col-md-12 mb-4">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <form onSubmit={this.changeVisibility}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <Text text="E-mail adresiniz" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <Input ph="E-mail" />
                    </div>
                    <Button clickText="İleri" />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
          </Animation>
        </div>
      )
    }}
  </UserConsumer>
)
```